# Create table & add a multiplication of 2 records from 2 other tables in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiplication

I have 2 tables, ID1, and say ID 2, with the same format.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ID1;
SELECT _Close into ID1
FROM livedata where ID = 1;
SELECT * FROM ID1;
```

The output of each table has just 1 record:

```
_Close
0.84931
```

I would like to create a new table, say xyz, that adds the multiplication of ID1 and ID2. I have tried this:

```
drop table if exists xyz;
select ID1._Close * ID10._Close into xyz;
```

But get these errors:

```
The multi-part identifier "ID1._Close" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 95
The multi-part identifier "ID10._Close" could not be bound.
Msg 1038, Level 15, State 5, Line 95
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
```

So what simply piece of code am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: You need a `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cross join the tables ID1 and ID2:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS xyz;
SELECT ID1._Close * ID2._Close _Close INTO xyz
FROM ID1 CROSS JOIN ID2;
SELECT * FROM xyz;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ccf981977c26115490be1306d40a066).

Comment: Perfect answer thank you. Have not heard of a cross join before. Not sure what  ID2._Close _Close does so I'll look into that. Thanks again. Steve

Comment: Check this: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-cross-join/ I use cross join because you say that each of the 2 tables contains only 1 row so the result of the cross join will also be 1 row.

Comment: `_Close` will be the name of the column which is the result of the multiplication in the table xyz .

Comment: The link is very useful to explain what is happening in the code; _Close now makes sense and I have accepted the answer. :) Thumbs up!